# "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" when I try to locateOnScreen in pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I just started using pyautogui and I'm trying to have it locate an image on the screen but it returns the error message I provided in the title. Here's the code:

```
import pyautogui
searching = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:\Users\Crack\OneDrive\Pictures\Screenshots\search.png')
print(searching)
```

I tried just saying locateOnScreen('search.png') but that outputted the same error message.

Comment: you need to use raw string for file locations in python for windows. put r'C:\...' and it will work.

Comment: wait so I put:
searching = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Users\Crack\OneDrive\Pictures\Screenshots\search.png')

Comment: Yes, provided the rest of the module syntax is correct. Remember backslash is an escape character in python so you either need to double them up in windows file paths, use raw strings or use the  sys module to get the filepath.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change back slash to forward slash

2) Also try adjust tolerance to your image matching if you get "None" as your result.

pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:/Users/Crack/OneDrive/Pictures/Screenshots/search.png',confidence=0.7)

Try confidence from lower number (e.g. 0.5) and keep adjusting to as high as possible.